# Google API shows duplicate rows for TransactionId's

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've got a strange problem.
I'm trying to pull out data from GA API.

metrics: ga:users
dimensions: ga:date,ga:source,ga:medium,ga:transactionId

After reviewing the data I can see that I have multiple transaction Id's.
Usually 5 to 7 duplicates per month - the same transaction ID is in two dates.

In Google Analytics there are no duplicates.
There are in the exported data + Query Explorer also shows duplicates.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks,
Krzysztof

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you make sure you use unique transactionIDs for each transaction? I've seen cases where the ERP makes certain transaction or orderIDs available again after an order was cancelled.

If you look at the transactionID in GA (click in on the ID itself to drill down into it) and change to Quantity or look at the product revenue for the graph line, do they occur on two different dates?

This behaviour is often seen if you forget to prevent the transaction pixel again on things like a page refresh. Another example is if they perhaps receive an email with "Click here to view your order/transaction" and it fires again on the receipt page.

Comment: Thanks, @MrSponge, We've found the issue: Safari browser (from time to time) double count the transactions. We'll try to build some prevention for that. Thanks Again